# How do I use the new iOS 6 methods to center text?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel, text-alignment

My Old Code

```
sectorLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Xcode is saying that textAlignment is deprecated. How do I use the new method?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It now uses the same as the properties for the Mac.

Use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` instead :D

HTH